# Understanding the following cpp snippet

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, bitcoin

This snippet is lifted from bitcoin code base.

```
struct CombinerAll
{
    typedef bool result_type;

    template<typename I>
    bool operator()(I first, I last) const
    {
        while (first != last) {
            if (!(*first)) return false;
            ++first;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

This gets used here

```
boost::signals2::signal<bool (CNode*), CombinerAll> ProcessMessages;
```

Can any c++ expert help me understand what the above (`CombinerAll` and `ProcessMessages` boost signal) does? Asking this because boost library is highly non-intuitive for me.

Comment: The [`boost.signals2`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/signals2.html) documentation is quite good. I would start by reading it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the function:

```
        if (!(*first)) return false;
```

If any of the elements in the range `[first, last)` evaluate to `false` when the pointer/iterator/object is dereferenced, the function returns `false`. Otherwise, it returns `true`.

Example test code:

```
int main()
{
   std::string sa = "abc";

   std::vector<int> va = {1, 1, 1};
   std::vector<int> vb = {1, 0, 2};

   std::cout << std::boolalpha;
   std::cout << CombinerAll()(sa.begin(), sa.end()) << std::endl;

   std::cout << CombinerAll()(va.begin(), va.end()) << std::endl;
   std::cout << CombinerAll()(vb.begin(), vb.end()) << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
true
true
false
```

Documentation for `boost::signals2::signal` can be found at [Boost website](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/signals2.html).

As to what `ProcessMessages` does, you have to consult the people who wrote that code.

Comment: Thank u for the clear explanation.  Actually I wanna know the meaning of the template line in particular. If my understanding is correct, we are overloading the () operator and making it do the loop computation when we call CombinerAll like a function?

Comment: @SandhyaKumar, that is correct.